# The modify coding button of idea does not take effect

Tags: intellij-idea

What steps will reproduce the issue?

1. This problem occurs when copying a configuration file to this idea
2. idea version 2021.3.3

What is the expected result?
Garbled characters are not allowed

What happens instead?
There are currently garbled characters

file->setting-> editor-> file Encoding

Set the encoding in this way, but the result is still garbled

Comment: The issue is not fully clear from the provided description. If the problem is IntelliJ IDEA specific please contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and share a couple of screenshots showing the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.